# How can I align one element to the right and another to the left side of my JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I created a `JPanel` and added two `JButtons` in it. I set the panel layout as `FlowLayout`.
I want one `JButton` to be on the left of the `JFrame` and the other `JButton` to be on the right.

I tried this but it's throwing an `IllegalArgumentException`:

```
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

        JButton login = new JButton("Login");
        JButton register = new JButton("Register");

        mainPanel.add(register, FlowLayout.RIGHT);
        mainPanel.add(login, FlowLayout.LEFT);
```

Can I do this using `FlowLayout`? Which layout would make it work?

Comment: do you mean `JPanel` instead of `JFrame`? Please show the stacktrace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mainPanel.add(register, FlowLayout.RIGHT);
mainPanel.add(login, FlowLayout.LEFT);
```

That is not how those FlowLayout variables are used. They are used as properties of the layout manager, not as a constraint for the add(…) method. Read the `FlowLayout` API for more information.

> I want one JButton to be on the left of the JFrame and the other JButton to be on the right. Can I do this using FlowLayout?

No.

> Which layout would make it work?

You could use a panel with a:

1. `BorderLayout` - add one button to the `BorderLayout.LINE_START` and one to the `BorderLayout.LINE_END`
2. `BoxLayout` - add a `Box.createHorizontalGlue()` between the two buttons.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and examples on each of the above layout managers.